# Can I use a different ItemRenderer for different list items?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have a Flex list and a custom ItemRenderer. I'd like to be able to have *some* items in the list use a different ItemRenderer (say, depending on the class of the item). Is this possible?

E.g.:

```
<s:List dataProvider="{_systems}" itemRenderer="myItemRenderer"/>
```

Most items in _systems use myItemRenderer. But if element 3 of _systems is "specialSystem" the renderer would be "specialItemRenderer".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [itemRendererFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html#itemRendererFunction).

Here is a [blog post tutorial on that](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/03/19/using-a-custom-item-renderer-function-with-the-fxlist-control-in-flex-gumbo/).  I also touch on [this here](http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/28/Flex-4-Lists--6262010---Episode-67--Flextras-Friday-Lunch).

Answer (score 1):

You use Canvas as ItemRenderer and implement mechanism which will create other controls automatically.

More details you can find in this article: [Different Items renderers in List](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Different_Items_renderers_in_List-2081.html)

The main idea:

> You create special ItemRenderer which
>   can create "emulate" other controls,
>   in our case it is subclass of Canvas
>   which simply creates and adds desired
>   control. Then we need some mechanism
>   to tell our container which renderer
>   we want to emulate, for this purpose we
>   use ItemContainerData with special
>   fields.

Comment: That would be the only approach for Flex 3, Halo lists.  But Flex 4 introduced the itemRendererFunction which will provide a much cleaner implementation.